# Error while starting gulp- Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]

Tags: gulp

I've been trying to solve the problems w gulp, but it won't start. Reinstall didn’t help, I tried to create the necessary files, because before that there was another error, it seemed to help, but now this one has come out and I can’t do anything with it

I know that there are alot of answers on that question, but i doesnt help

```
$ gulp -v
CLI version: 2.3.0
Local version: 3.9.1
```

```
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module D:\litshop\node_modules\gulp-autoprefixer\index.js from D:\litshop\gulpfile.js not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in D:\litshop\gulpfile.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\litshop\gulpfile.js:6:22) {
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
```

I just wanna start gulp. Tried to uninstall and insall again node.js, gulp